# How to write strings into csv from xpath in one cell?

Tags: python, xpath, export-to-csv

I get content "number1" and " number2” with code below, which are like "A", ['B', 'C']. However, in .csv file, B and C are not in the same cell which I want. How to get ['B', 'C'] in one cell. Also, I have multiple newlines.

```
  html = etree.HTML(res.text)
    number1 = html.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Eva")]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()')[0]
    number2 = html.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Jack")]/following-sibling::td[1]/span/text()')[0]
    mes = '%s,%s' % (str(number1), str(number2))
    mes.split()
    print(i, mes + '\n')
    with open('D:/test.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
        f.write(mes+'\n')
```

Comment: you should use module `csv` to write and read - it can resolve many problems

Comment: if you have mamy newlines that means you fogot to remove newline from data which you get from HTML - ie. `numer1 = numer1.strip()`

Comment: string `"A", ['B', 'C']` has tree columns - first `"A"`, second: `['B'`, third `'C']`. To have two columns you have to put text which have `,` inside `" "` - `"A", "['B', 'C']"`. Module `csv` adds it automatically. BTW: similar problem you may have with newline in text - you have to put text in `" "` to treat as one item instead of two rows. Module `csv` adds it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to fix your XPath with the following-ones (add `normalize-space()` to exclude whitespace nodes and `translate` to remove the whitespace in `number2`). You can also remove the `","` when you concat the string, otherwise the `split()` with no argument won't work :

```
number1 = html.xpath('//td[contains(text(),"Eva")]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()[normalize-space()]')[0]

number2 = html.xpath('translate(//td[contains(text(),"Jack")]/following-sibling::td[1]/span/text()[normalize-space()]," ","")')

mes = '%s %s' % (str(number1), str(number2))
```

Example :

```
data = """HTML
<table>
<td>15</td>
<td>18, 43</td>
</table>
HTML"""

import lxml.html
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(data)
number1=tree.xpath('//td[1]/text()')[0]
number2=tree.xpath('translate(//td[2]/text()," ","")')

#mes=number1+" "+number2
mes = '%s %s' % (str(number1),str(number2))
print(mes.split())
```

Output :

```
['15', '18,43']
```